# Installing wine with osxwinebuilder

Tags: install, homebrew, wine

I try to install wine with [osxwinebuilder](https://code.google.com/p/osxwinebuilder/). When I do, I get the following error:

```
...
checking if ccache g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if ccache g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the ccache g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin12.2.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking ltdl.h usability... no
checking ltdl.h presence... no
checking for ltdl.h... no
checking that we can compile and link with libltdl... no
configure: error: cannot compile and link against libltdl
libgphoto2 requires libltdl (the libtool dl* library),
but cannot compile and link against it.
Aborting.

could not run configure command './configure --prefix=/Users/scott/wine/wine-1.5.16 --enable-shared=yes --enable-static=no --with-libexif=auto' in /Users/scott/wine/build/libgphoto2-2.4.14 - exiting
```

I am confused as what I should do. I have homebrew installed - should I install anything?

Answer (score 1):

I will hazard the guess that you need to install libtool.  You can do that with

```
brew install libtool
brew link libtool
```

From what I understand, libltdl is provided with that.
http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Using-libltdl.html

I don't actually use homebrew so I hope that my stab in the dark helps you find your solution!